# Yii - Route without Controller

Tags: yii

I'm using an existing upload script that require user authentication. However since I did not write the upload script, it's nearly impossible for me to read the source code and make it into separate view and controller file. The problem is if the script does not get routed by the bootstrap file, it has no access to the Yii variable and thus user log in information.

I tried to set a custom session variable when the user login. However it work barely because my custom session would expire before the session set by Yii.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem with more effort and in figurative way.

Comment: Okay let's try this again. If I don't have controller and view file, how can I create a route that will make Yii direct to a script file on the server (e.g localhost/upload.php)

Comment: Can your Yii app access the same database as the upload script?

Comment: Are you able to relocate the script file to another folder? Is the script file self-contained, or does it rely on other files for its operation?

Comment: @JoeMiller The script I'm using is this responsivefilemanager.com which has a bootstrap file config.php and other operational php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way the script is written I've only been able to find one way of doing this. It will involve re-writing some elements of the script.

1. Save the filemanager in protected/vendors.
2. You need a controller to handle the routing of the request. This will also give you the access control that you need. Call it FileUpload and create it where you normally create controllers in your project. Right at the start of the controller, before the class is declared, import the fileUpload files from it's previously saved location; `Yii::import('application.vendors.*');`
3. You need an action to handle the incoming request. Call this actionIndex. Give it the following code.

   ```
   public function actionIndex() {
       //Start capturing the output from the script
       ob_start();
       require_once('filemanager/dialog.php');

       //Finish capturing output, and save to a variable
       $output = ob_end_clean();
       $this->render('index', array('output' => $output));
   }
   ```
4. Then you need a view file. Call it 'output.php' and it just contains one line; `<?php echo $output; ?>`

This will render the html generated by the script, and hopefully contain it within your existing template.

Your first problem is that the script sends headers which aren't discarded by ob_start. You will need to delete these from the script. It also starts a session, which will throw an error 'Session already started', which can be cured by changing the first line of config.php to

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }
```

Your next problem will be that none of the scripts and stylesheets are loaded, because the vendor hasn't used relative filepaths, and also because you've just deleted the headers. You will need to re-write lots of the script to include the necessary files. Fortunately, you now have access to Yii functions, so can use the asset manager to publish all the js and css files needed by the script.

Your final (hopefully!) problem will be the urls used by the script page. Currently they are all pointing to files within the script. You will need to rewrite these to use Yii routing. Fortunately, inside the main file dialog.php you should have access to all the normal Yii functions, so you can set $baseUrl as $this->createUrl() etc. If you need to add extra actions to the controller you can follow the pattern above to call other files, like the upload.php file in the script.

Hope that all works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Framework with mvc pattern so controllers are preferred way to route requests .As per your problem i would suggest you to use htaccess file to do the routing to the required file and handle other files by Yii

Answer (score 0):

copy code from existing source to new Yii Controler/Action ... done :D